# General-purpose database GUI software for cataloging

Tags: open-source, database, gui, sqlite, catalog

I recall coming across an open-source, user-oriented (local) database software which allows generic use of a database engine (SQLite if I recall correctly), it would be perticularly nice for cataloging things.

It had a prominent GUI which allowed easy viewing of the data, along with filters etc.

Unfortunately I forgot to star this project on GitHub and I can no longer find it, I am pretty sure I came across it when browsing GitHub but I do not remember what I was browsing at that time.

Thank you for the help in advance, I really appriciate it!

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I am running Linux, but I appreciate suggestions for any platform! Cross-platform software is preferred obviously :)

Comment: I'm not going to post an answer since I have no actual experience with these, but you might look at Kexi (http://www.kexi-project.org/) or Symphytum (https://github.com/giowck/symphytum).

Comment: Look at this page: https://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools. There I found https://sqlitestudio.pl/ which looks like a possibility.

Comment: Wow, Symphytum is actually the software I was looking for, thank you very much for coming up with these recommendations. If you have the time, please post an answer so I can upvote and accept it. I currently do not have enough points to upvote comments :(

Comment: I posted an answer. Normally I avoid answering questions unless I have personal experience with the program, but since you so nicely asked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have personal experience using these programs, but I did find the following possibilities. [Symphytum](https://github.com/giowck/symphytum) is free and open source personal database software. It runs on Windows, Linux and MacOS. It looks pretty nice. Another I'm aware of is [KEXI](http://www.kexi-project.org/). It attempts to rival MS Access and Filemaker while being open source. It is available for Windows and Linux but not MacOS. Lastly if you are looking at GUIs specifically for SQLite, I did find the following page at the SQLite site with options: https://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools.

Comment: Thank you! Symphytum is actually what I am looking for, but the other suggestions look useful too, thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

[LibreOffice Base](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/) fits the bill, it offers a comprehensive GUI to manage a local general-purpose database.

Comment: But this is not the software that I am looking for, the GUI in the software that I recall has a much simpler GUI.