# Slim GUI tool for cataloguing notes (recipes) with filter function

Tags: windows, gui, catalog

I am looking for a slim tool to manage my recipe collection. What I have in mind, however, would not be designed for recipes. I don't want to create shopping lists or have to enter every ingredient at a time with a specified amount. Actually, I only want entries with plain text that I can filter (say by ingredient or by season or by effort).
So one recipe or rather meal would read: "chili: comfort food, quick, beans, vegetarian, can be precooked" and when I filter for one of these words, it'll turn up in a list. I can add various notes/links/sources in the same entry. Separate tags would not be needed because I can just write them in the entry itself.
The tool I am looking for could also be used to catalogue bike routes (filter for "summer, river, 2 hours") or anything really.

I am not familiar with databases, maybe I'm looking for a database GUI? On an older [question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/74397/general-purpose-database-gui-software-for-cataloging) [Symphytum](https://github.com/giowck/symphytum) turned up which has not been maintained since 2020 but which might go in the right direction. Is there anything comparable?
The nearest recipe-dedicated app I could find which looks very good and slim is [AnyMeal](https://wedesoft.github.io/anymeal/).

The tool should run on Windows.